# Choosing $1,2,3, \dots N$ objects from $N$ objects without replacement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I am not sure if I titled this correctly but here is my problem and would appreciate a way to title this if one can. Anyway, let's say you have $N$ objects total, say $N=4$ for illustration, which are numbered sequentially from $1$ to $N$:

$$1,2,3,4,\dots$$

How many ways can I choose $1$ object, $2$ objects, $1$ and $2$ objects, $2$ and $3$ objects, $1$,$2$ and $3$ objects ... $N$ objects.

I will try to illustrate what I mean with parenthesis which represent chosen objects. Note, I am wrapping the right-side of the list to the left-side like a circle. Is their some general formula for this problem with $N$ objects? I get $T$ ($=12$ for the illustration below) total possible ways and if I wanted say the possible ways for choosing k less than N objects (for less than $3$ gives $7$ ways for the illustration) then what would be general formulas for these?

$$(1)(2)(3)(4)  \\
(1,2)(3)(4)  \\
(1,2)(3,4)  \\
(1)(2,3)(4)  \\
1)(2,3)(4,  \\
(1)(2)(3,4)  \\
1)(2)(3)(4,  \\
(1,2,3)(4)  \\
(1)(2,3,4)  \\
1)(2)(3,4,  \\
1,2)(3)(4,  \\
(1,2,3,4)  $$

Comment: what is the difference for your 4th and 5th line? (1)(2,3)(4)  and 1)(2,3)(4, ?

Comment: 1)…(4, means (4,1)

Answer (score 3):

I have a sense that there might be a name for this problem, but I am not aware of it on top of my head. However, it is possible to derive a closed-form formula this problem, which I will informally refer to as the "circular partitioning" problem.

Let $T: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a function that returns the number of circular partitions, i.e., $T(n)$ gives the number of ways of partitioning the circular $n$-tuple $(1, \dots, n)$, as demonstrated in the example above. Then the formula is given by

$$
T(n) = 2^n - n.
$$

The intuition is as follows. Consider a round table with seats labeled from 1 to $n$. We can imagine placing dividers between any two adjacent seats. If a divider is placed, we consider it as demarcating a boundary of a partition, analogous to the parentheses in the example above. Then there are $n$ total possible divider locations, with a binary choice of either placing or not placing a divider. Hence, $2^n$.

However, as it stands, this solution over-counts the case $(1, \dots, n)$, i.e., when no dividers are placed. Taking $n = 4$ as an example, $(1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), ...$ are all identical. These configurations can be achieved in $(n + 1)$ ways: place no dividers, or place 1 divider, with $n$ total ways. Therefore, we subtract $n$ to remove duplicate counts.

Taking $n = 4$ for a quick sanity check, the formula returns $T(4) = 2^4 - 4 = 12$, which matches the manual result.

Comment: Thank you. How might you calculate for N objects the number of times that partitionings give only subgroupings of size less than K. In the example for N=4, for only subgroupings with sizes less than k=3. I get 7/12 in my example.

Answer (score 1):

About the second question: let $c(n, k)$ be the number of "circular compositions" of $n$ points into parts of size at most $k$.  (So, in your example, $c(4, 3) = 7$.)  And let $\ell(n, k)$ be the number of "linear compositions" of $n$ points into parts of size at most $k$ -- equivalently, they are the circular compositions in which we do not allow a part to wrap around to include both $1$ and $n$.  These numbers do not have nice formulas, but they do have simple recurrences: first, by considering the size of the last part, we have $$
\ell(n, k) = \ell(n - 1, k) + \ell(n - 2, k) + \ldots + \ell(n - k, k)
$$ (where for all $k$ we understand $\ell(0, k) = 1$ and $\ell(m, k) = 0$ if $m < 0$).  Second, by considering the size and position of the part containing $n$, we have $$
c(n, k) = \ell(n - 1, k) + 2 \cdot \ell(n - 2, k) + \ldots + k \cdot \ell(n - k, k)
$$ if $n > k$ (and of course $c(n, k) = 2^n - n$ if $n \leq k$ per Jake Tae's answer).

You could presumably also package the information above in a generating function, if you wanted to.